# Ubuntu 22.04 hanging in recovery mode

Tags: boot, grubrescue, recovery-mode

I am trying to boot into recovery mode.
On boot type the right shift key loads the GRUB menu V. 2.06
Selecting `Advanced options for Ubuntu`
Selecting `Ubuntu, with Linux 5.16.0-47-generic (recovery mode)`

```
Loading Linux 5.15.0-47-generic ...
Loading initial ramdisk ...
_
```

and nothing happens
any advice?
thank you

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS; `5.16.0-47-generic` is not a *supported* Ubuntu 22.04 LTS kernel.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I boot with an older kernel version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82140/how-can-i-boot-with-an-older-kernel-version)

Comment: Hi, no it does not. It is the kernel provided by the system. And, also `Loading Linux 5.15.0-43-generic` is non responsive.

Comment: Maybe to fix this I need to install older more stable kernals??

Comment: 5.15 is *stable* for *jammy* or 22.04, 5.16 was *testing* only and is not deemed *stable*.